# Referencing appendix returns chapter number instead of letter (memoir class)

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices

I'm using an adapted version of the memoir class to typeset my thesis. I'm attempting to add an appendix, which I will reference in various chapters. Here is the basic code (to compile, need ukthesis class which can be found here math.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/ukthesis.cls_.txt ):

```
\documentclass[final]{ukthesis}
%you must include these 2 packages.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{General Introduction}

 In \textbf{Appendix \ref{app:A}}, alongside CAD diagrams.

%-----------------------------------------------
\backmatter
\newpage
\appendix
\chapter{Detector Frame Drawings}\label{app:A}
The following pages show drawings 
\end{document}
```

However, when I attempt to reference it, what I get back out is something like:

"See appendix 2.3.3" (or in the case of this MWE, I just get a blank reference value)

instead of the expected:

"See appendix A."

Thoughts on what could be causing this? Forgive me if this is answered elsewhere, but I couldn't locate someone with this same problem, and other suggestions (for various other problems) haven't worked.

Thanks,
Zach

EDITED: to include an actual MWE.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) Full minimal compilable example please. If I just add `\documentclass{memoir}` to your example and compile a few times I get the expected `appendix A`, so there seems to be something you are not telling us.

Comment: I'm using a version of the memoir class that is added to by my university for their template. They provide a file called ukthesis.cls, but it just adds the beginning pages and format, then loads the memoir class. I also seem to be getting the correct "A" from this example now (though I wasn't when I posted it 5 minutes ago). Will attempt to make a MCE that isn't working.

Comment: It seems the problem is in the ukthesis file. I'm unsure what's causing it, but removing that as an input document class solves the problem. I will work this out separately, since debugging a document class type is not what I had originally asked. Thanks for your input, daleif.

Comment: Is that class downloadable somewhere?

Comment: https://math.as.uky.edu/sites/default/files/ukthesis.cls_.txt

Comment: That works fine for me too. Please update your question with an exact MWE including relevant preamble and document class, with information about where the non-standard class can be downloaded. Just adding `\documentclass{ukthesis}` to your current example works just fine.

Comment: It is updated now to include an actual working example.

Comment: Remove the `\backmatter` command, it does the same as `\frontmatter`, ie switches off the numbering. And thus your labels will get the latest *something*.

Comment: Also you should not define your `siunitx` shortcuts like that, `siunitx` has build in features for that. And why are you adding the bibliography *before* the appendices, it is usually the other way round.

Comment: I put the bibliography there, because that's where it is in the sample thesis. As far as siunitX, I couldn't get their built in thing to work without typing \si{\meter} every time. I wanted something shorter, so that I could just type \meter. I have added a new, shorter MWE that returns the wrong type of label for me now.

Comment: As I said, remove `\backmatter`, it does not do you any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\backmatter` stops any chapter numbering, so put your appendix before that. In any case bibliographies and indexes normally come after appendices.

Comment: Ahh, that's it. The example thesis they gave has appendix at the very very end. Thank you. Thanks to everyone else for help as well.

Comment: I feel a bit embarassed that i didn't spot the `\backmatter`, but I am glad to see that the `memoir` experts are supporting as well.

Answer (score 2):

Trimming down the code to

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter{BLAH}
See appendix \ref{app:A}.
\chapter{Concerning Hobbits}\label{app:A}
\end{document}
```

makes you realize: There was never a `\mainmatter` issued, so no chapter is numbered. The same behaviour will happen when issuing `\backmatter`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\mainmatter<-------------
\chapter{BLAH}
See appendix \ref{app:A}.
\chapter{Concerning Hobbits}\label{app:A}
\backmatter
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, I'm sorry. I am very new (3 days) to LaTeX. My main document does have a \mainmatter. However, it still does not label correctly. I seem to be unable to get an MWE that isn't just the whole document with most of the text removed. The document is already quite large though.

Comment: I have added the full backmatter from my document to the initial post, perhaps that will be somehow enlightening.

Comment: Nicola Talbot wrote a few lines on [how to prepare a minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). You will be able to strip the document down within half an hour. Right now i can't even guess.

Comment: No, not enlightening. Sorry.

Comment: Okay a new MWE is up now. For me, this returns, instead of "Appendix A" it comes as "Appendix 1.1." Also, the appendix does not add a "Appendix A" title to it's title.

Comment: Have to say i'm sorry, the `\backmatter` was there and i just overlooked it. Both behave in the same way.